# Will SCIP handle divided by 0 automatically?

Tags: optimization, scip

I'm using SCIP in C++ to solve a minlp problem.
In my model, I try to implement an expression to compare two variables. If they are equal, the output is 0, and otherwise it outputs 1.

Let them be varA and varB and both are integers.

Is it safe to write a SCIP expression like (varA - varB) / (varA - varB)?
If not, is there a build-in expression in SCIP for comparison of two variables?

Comment: are the variables binary, continuous or integer?

Comment: Both are integers, I've edited the question to make it more readable.

Comment: I don't think 0/0 is equal to 0.

Answer (score 0):

You could use indicator constraints for that. E.g.:

```
δ = δ1+δ2
δ = 0 => x=y
δ1 = 1 => x≥y+1
δ2 = 1 => y≥x+1
δ,δ1,δ2 ∈ {0,1}
```

Comment: Can I set a variable z = | x - y | and create an indicator constraint as you introduced for it?

Comment: Sure. Not sure if it will perform much better though.